# Extract plaintext from HTML when webpage doesn't use CSS

Tags: c#, html, css, text

Part of the project I'm working on involves getting text from webpages. I've tried to adapt this code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class Program
{
    private string _plainText;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program();
    }
    private Program()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(“> “);
            string phrase = Console.ReadLine();
            if (phrase.Length > 0)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(GetPlainText));
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start(phrase);
                thread.Join();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(_plainText);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
    private void GetPlainText(object phrase)
    {
        string uri = “”;
        WebBrowser _webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        _webBrowser.Url = new Uri(string.Format(@”http://www.google.com/search?as_q={0}&as_sitesearch=www.bbc.co.uk/news”, phrase));
        while (_webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Application.DoEvents();
        foreach (HtmlElement a in _webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName(“A”))
        {
            uri = a.GetAttribute(“href”);
            if (uri.StartsWith(“http://www.bbc.co.uk/news”)) break;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.Url = new Uri(uri);
        while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Application.DoEvents();
        // Pick out the main heading.
        foreach (HtmlElement h1 in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName(“H1”))
            sb.Append(h1.InnerText + “. “);
        // Select only the article text, ignoring everything else.
        foreach (HtmlElement div in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName(“DIV”))
            if (div.GetAttribute(“classname”) == “story-body”)
                foreach (HtmlElement p in div.GetElementsByTagName(“P”))
                {
                    string classname = p.GetAttribute(“classname”);
                    if (classname == “introduction” || classname == “”)
                        sb.Append(p.InnerText + ” “);
                }
        webBrowser.Dispose();
        _plainText = sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

To search the website I'm working with (i.e. changing instances of "www.bbc.co.uk" to the site I'm using), however when I came to find which CSS class the text portion of the page is in, it seems the site doesn't use CSS. Is there a  good workaround for getting plaintext from a website where it doesn't use CSS?

Comment: You have smart quotes in your source. But apart from that, I fail to see how extracting text from a HTML document depends on the absence of presence of CSS.

Comment: I've fixed the quotes in my own version. The problem is that I don't know what to change in the line 'if (div.GetAttribute(“classname”) == “story-body”)' as there is no classname.